# aws-amplify with Auth0

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, auth0

We've got Auth0 and aws-amplify working separately for our React Native App.  But, going the next step (even following the Auth0 and AWS docs) for getting the authentication to flow from Auth0 to Cognito/User-Pools has not been working.

Yet, we've not found discussion on stack overflow, or Auth0 or others with the same problem.  Is it possible that we are missing something?

aws-amplify does imply that OpenID Connect and Federated Identities are working, but its possible that the library is not yet supporting this flow.

refs: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/58
      https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/integrating-auth0-amazon-cognito-mobile-apps
      https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/open-id.html

Does anyone have a working example or other docs that we could use to debug the flow?  Right now it defaults to the guest/unauth route after Auth0 and aws-amplify communicate, rather then enabling authentication to flow and our policies to be applied for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Hi we have this feature request in the repo. https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/239

Comment: Trying to follow your docs https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#federated-with-auth0 has me puzzled. Can you provide a sample working code to add the button to login with auth0 whilst maintaining the standard login flow? Mainly because this is how I am exporting in App.js `export default connect()(withAuthenticator(withStyles(styles)(App), { signUpConfig }));`